# Wait for Ping and notify

Tags: windows, networking, services, ping

Is there a utility that works in the background and is able to notify me if my computer is being pinged?

Comment: If such a utility exists, I'd expect it to be part of a Desktop-PC firewall or Desktop-PC security suite.

Comment: Now that's just paranoia.

Answer (score 0):

Ping packets are actually ICMP echo request packets. You can check [wikipedia to better understand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping/).

As RedGrittyBrick sayed, this is often a part of Firewall applications. You can however try to block ICMP requests through your home router and watch the log for detected ICMP echo requests.

Answer (score 0):

[windump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/) (tcpdump for windows) will tell you everything you want to know about any pings your NIC receives.